# Create dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a dataframe in a loop and after use these dataframe in a loop. I tried eval() function but it didn't work.

For example :

```
for i in range(5):
    df_i = df[(df.age == i)]
```

There I would like to create `df_0`,`df_1` etc. And then concatenate these new dataframe after some calculations :

```
final_df = pd.concat(df_0,df_1)

for i in range(2:5):
    final_df = pd.concat(final_df, df_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict of DataFrames `x` and have `i`s as dict keys:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.randint(0, 5, 20)})

x = {}
for i in range(5):
    x[i] = df[df['age']==i]

final = pd.concat(x.values())
```

Then you can refer to individual DataFrames as:

```
x[1]
```

Output:

```
    age
5     1
13    1
15    1
```

And concatenate all of them with:

```
pd.concat(x.values())
```

Output:

```
    age
18    0
5     1
13    1
15    1
2     2
6     2
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it possible to give a name to the dataframe depending on i ? In fact, I will create dataframe depending on double loop...

Comment: Technically, yes, you can create variables with exec like `exec(f"df_{i} = df[df['age']==i]")`, but it's normally not recommended. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

The way is weird and not recommended, but it can be done.

**Answer**

```
for i in range(5):
    exec("df_{i} = df[df['age']=={i}]")

def UDF(dfi):
    # do something in user-defined function

for i in range(5):
    exec("df_{i} = UDF(df_{i})")

final_df = pd.concat(df_0,df_1)

for i in range(2:5):
    final_df = pd.concat(final_df, df_i)
```

**Better Way 1**

Using a list or a dict to store the dataframe should be a better way since you can access each dataframe by an index or a key.

Since another answer shows the way using dict (@perl), I will show you the way using list.

```
def UDF(dfi):
    # do something in user-defined function

dfs = [df[df['age']==i] for i in range(i)]
final_df = pd.concat(map(UDF, dfs))
```

**Better Way 2**

Since you are using pandas.DataFrame, `groupby` function is a 'pandas' way to do what you want. (maybe, I guess, cause I don't know what you want to do. LOL)

```
def UDF(dfi):
    # do something in user-defined function

final_df = df.groupby('age').apply(UDF)
```

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html